# How do we prove the n-step return error reduction property?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, q-learning, math, proofs, sutton-barto

In section 7.1 (about the n-step bootstrapping) of the book *Reinforcement Learning: An Introduction* (2nd edition), by Andrew Barto and Richard S. Sutton, the authors write about what they call the "n-step return error reduction property":

[image]

But they don't prove it. I was thinking it should not be too hard but how can we show this? I was thinking of using the definition of n-step return (eq. 7.1 on previous page):

$$G_{t:t+n} = R_{t+1} + \gamma*R_{t+2} + ... + \gamma^{n-1}*R_{t+n} + \gamma^{n}*V_{t+n-1}(S_{t+n})$$

Because then this has the $V_{t+n-1}$ in it already. But in the definition above of the n-step return it uses $V_{t+n-1}(S_{t+n})$ but on the right side of the inequality (7.3) that we want to prove it is just little s $V_{t+n-1}(s)$ ? So kind of confused here which state s it is using? And then I guess after this probably pull out a $\gamma^{n}$ term or something, how should we go from here?

This is the newest Sutton Barto book (book page 144, equation 7.3):
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1opPSz5AZ_kVa1uWOdOiveNiBFiEOHjkG/view

Answer (score 10):

Let's start by looking at:

$$\max_s \Bigl\lvert \mathbb{E}_{\pi} \left[ G_{t:t+n} \mid S_t = s \right] - v_{\pi}(s) \Bigr\rvert.$$

We can rewrite this by plugging in the definition of $G_{t:t+n}$:

\begin{aligned}
& \max_s \Bigl\lvert \mathbb{E}_{\pi} \left[ G_{t:t+n} \mid S_t = s \right] - v_{\pi}(s) \Bigr\rvert \\
%
=& \max_s \Bigl\lvert \mathbb{E}_{\pi} \left[ R_{t + 1} + \gamma R_{t + 2} + \dots + \gamma^{n - 1} R_{t + n} + \gamma^n V_{t + n - 1}(S_{t + n}) \mid S_t = s \right] - v_{\pi}(s) \Bigr\rvert \\
%
=& \max_s \Bigl\lvert \mathbb{E}_{\pi} \left[ R_{t:t+n} + \gamma^n V_{t + n - 1}(S_{t + n}) \mid S_t = s \right] - v_{\pi}(s) \Bigr\rvert,
\end{aligned}

where $R_{t:t+n} \doteq R_{t + 1} + \gamma R_{t + 2} + \dots + \gamma^{n - 1} R_{t + n}$.

If you go all the way back to page 58 of the book, you can see the definition of $v_{\pi}(s)$:

\begin{aligned}
v_{\pi}(s) &\doteq \mathbb{E}_{\pi} \left[ \sum_{k = 0}^{\infty} \gamma^k R_{t + k + 1} \mid S_t = s \right] \\
%
&= \mathbb{E}_{\pi} \left[ R_{t:t+n} + \gamma^n \sum_{k = 0}^{\infty} \gamma^k R_{t + n + k + 1} \mid S_t = s \right] \\
%
&= \mathbb{E}_{\pi} \left[ R_{t:t+n} \mid S_t = s \right] + \gamma^n \mathbb{E}_{\pi} \left[ \sum_{k = 0}^{\infty} \gamma^k R_{t + n + k + 1} \mid S_t = s \right]
\end{aligned}

Using this, we can continue rewriting where we left off above:

\begin{aligned}
& \max_s \Bigl\lvert \mathbb{E}_{\pi} \left[ R_{t:t+n} + \gamma^n V_{t + n - 1}(S_{t + n}) \mid S_t = s \right] - v_{\pi}(s) \Bigr\rvert \\
%
=& \max_s \Bigl\lvert \mathbb{E}_{\pi} \left[ \gamma^n V_{t + n - 1}(S_{t + n}) \mid S_t = s \right] - \gamma^n \mathbb{E}_{\pi} \left[ \sum_{k = 0}^{\infty} \gamma^k R_{t + n + k + 1} \mid S_t = s \right] \Bigr\rvert \\
%
=& \gamma^n \max_s \Bigl\lvert \mathbb{E}_{\pi} \left[ V_{t + n - 1}(S_{t + n}) - \sum_{k = 0}^{\infty} \gamma^k R_{t + n + k + 1} \mid S_t = s \right] \Bigr\rvert
\end{aligned}

Because the absolute value function is [convex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_function), we can use [Jensen's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality) to show that the absolute value of an expectation is less than or equal to the expectation of the corresponding absolute value:

$$\left| \mathbb{E} \left[ X \right] \right| \leq \mathbb{E} \left[ \left| X \right| \right].$$

This means that:

\begin{aligned}
\max_s \Bigl\lvert \mathbb{E}_{\pi} \left[ G_{t:t+n} - v_{\pi}(s) \mid S_t = s \right] \Bigr\rvert &\leq \gamma^n \max_s \mathbb{E}_{\pi} \left[ \Bigl\lvert V_{t + n - 1}(S_{t + n}) - \sum_{k = 0}^{\infty} \gamma^k R_{t + n + k + 1} \Bigr\rvert \mid S_t = s \right] \\
%
\end{aligned}

Now, the important trick here is to see that:

$$\max_s \mathbb{E}_{\pi} \left[ \Bigl\lvert V_{t + n - 1}(S_{t + n}) - \sum_{k = 0}^{\infty} \gamma^k R_{t + n + k + 1} \Bigr\rvert \mid S_t = s \right] \leq \max_s \mathbb{E}_{\pi} \left[ \Bigl\lvert V_{t + n - 1}(S_{t}) - \sum_{k = 0}^{\infty} \gamma^k R_{t + k + 1} \Bigr\rvert \mid S_t = s \right]$$

I'm skipping the formal steps to show that this is the case to save space, but the intuition is that:

- The left-hand side of this inequality involves finding an $S_t = s$ such that some function of $S_{t + n}$ is maximized, whereas the right-hand side involves finding an $S_t = s$ such that exactly the same function of $S_{t}$ is maximized.
- In the left-hand side, selecting an $S_t = s$ implicitly induces a probability distribution over multiple possible states $S_{t + n}$, given by $S_t$, the environment's transition dynamics, and the policy $\pi$. Intuitively, this is more "restrictive" for the $\max$ operator, it does not have the "freedom" to directly select a single state $S_{t + n}$ such that the function of $S_{t + n}$ is maximized. The right-hand side is free to choose any single state $S_t = s$ such that $S_t$ in the right-hand side were equal to an "optimal" $S_{t+n}$ on the left-hand side, but it is also free to make even better choices which might never be uniquely reachable after $n$ steps on the left-hand side.

We can use this to rewrite the previous inequality we had (where we might be making the right-hand side a bit bigger than it was, but that's fine, it already was an upper bound anyway so that inequality will still hold):

\begin{aligned}
\max_s \Bigl\lvert \mathbb{E}_{\pi} \left[ G_{t:t+n} - v_{\pi}(s) \mid S_t = s \right] \Bigr\rvert &\leq \gamma^n \max_s \mathbb{E}_{\pi} \left[ \Bigl\lvert V_{t + n - 1}(S_{t}) - \sum_{k = 0}^{\infty} \gamma^k R_{t + k + 1} \Bigr\rvert \mid S_t = s \right] \\
%
&= \gamma^n \max_s \mathbb{E}_{\pi} \left[ \Bigl\lvert V_{t + n - 1}(S_{t}) - v_{\pi}(s) \Bigr\rvert \mid S_t = s \right].
\end{aligned}

After this rewriting we've got a hidden $\mathbb{E}_{\pi}$ "inside" another $\mathbb{E}_{\pi}$ (because the definition of $v_{\pi}(s)$ contains an $\mathbb{E}_{\pi}$), which I suppose is kind of ugly... but mathematically meaningless.

The maximum of a random variable is an upper bound on the expectation of that random variable, so we can get rid of the expectation in the right-hand side (again potentially increasing the right-hand side, which again is still fine since it's already an upper bound anyway):

\begin{aligned}
\max_s \Bigl\lvert \mathbb{E}_{\pi} \left[ G_{t:t+n} - v_{\pi}(s) \mid S_t = s \right] \Bigr\rvert &\leq \gamma^n \max_s \Bigl\lvert V_{t + n - 1}(s) - v_{\pi}(s) \Bigr\rvert,
\end{aligned}

which we can finally rewrite to Equation (7.3) in the book by moving the subtraction of $v_{\pi}(s)$ outside of the expectation on the left-hand side of the inequality (which is fine because, as I already mentioned above, the definition of $v_{\pi}(s)$ itself contains another $\mathbb{E}_{\pi}$ anyway).

Comment: Your bullet points explaining the "trick" make intuitive sense. Could you provide a link to someone showing the formal steps?

Comment: @PhilipRaeisghasem I don't know of any such links by heart, so can't provide one, sorry :(

Comment: I'd argue that, if it's that hard to find this information, then including it in the post would greatly increase the post's value. Or maybe as a separate, linked question?

Comment: @PhilipRaeisghasem Absolutely, either would be fine... maybe separate question better, since this one's already fairly long. I'm currently working towards a paper submission deadline though, so I really don't personally feel like working out the math and writing it all down any time soon.

Comment: Can we just say that s_t+1 is a subset of s therefore its max over s_t+1 must <= max over s?

Comment: @Phizaz Hmmm not exactly. Close to that, I'd say "given a completely free, unrestricted choice for $S_t$, the set of possible states $S_{t+n}$ is a subset of the set of possible states $S_t$". Very often it will not be a proper subset though, very often they'll be equal. But even then, a very important other point is that the **probability distributions** over those sets will be different. When the choice of $S_t$ is unrestricted, you can assign full probability mass to whichever is "best". Even if that best state may still be possible for $S_{t+n}$, it may no longer have full probability mass

Comment: @DennisSoemers I agree. However, will we not be able to prove without the probability mass argument?

Comment: @Phizaz Ah yes I think you're completely right. Intuitively it didn't "feel" right to me to omit that... but I guess math doesn't care about my feelings :)

Comment: how to intuitively understand the error reduction property? how does this guarantee the convergence?

Answer (score 1):

I will try to answer the question in a lesser mathematical (and hopefully correct way).

NOTE: I have used $V_{\pi}$ and $v_{\pi}$ interchangeably.

We start from LHS:

$$\max_s \Bigl\lvert \mathbb{E}_{\pi} \left[ G_{t:t+n} \mid S_t = s \right] - v_{\pi}(s) \Bigr\rvert$$

This can be written in terms of trajectories. Say the probability of observing a $n$ step trajectory (for a $n$ step return) is $p_j^{s}$ from state $S_t = s$ . Thus we can write the expected return as sum of returns from all trajectories multiplied with the probability of the trajectory:

$$\mathbb{E}_{\pi}  [G_{t:t+n}|S_t = s] = \sum_j p_j^sG_{t:t+n}^j = \sum_j p_j^s [R_{t+1}^j + \gamma R_{t+2}^j.....\gamma^{n-1}R_{t+n}^j + \gamma^n V_{t+n-1}(S_{t + n})^j]$$

We use @Dennis's terminology for $n$ step rewards i.e

$R_{t:t+n}^j \doteq R_{t + 1}^j + \gamma R_{t + 2}^j + \dots + \gamma^{n - 1} R_{t + n}^j$.

Now we know $v_{\pi}(s)$ is nothing but $\mathbb{E}_{\pi}  [G_{t:t+n}^{\pi}|S_t = s]$ where I have used $G_{t:t+n}^{\pi}$ to denote that the returns are actual returns if we have evaluated the policy completely (the value functions are consistent with the policy) for every state(using infinite episodes maybe) i.e $G_{t:t+n}^{\pi} = R_{t:t+n} + \gamma^n V_{\pi}(S_{t + n})$.

So now if we evaluate the equation:

$$\max_s \Bigl\lvert \mathbb{E}_{\pi} \left[ G_{t:t+n} \mid S_t = s \right] - v_{\pi}(s) \Bigr\rvert = \max_s \Bigl\lvert \mathbb{E}_{\pi} \left[ G_{t:t+n} \mid S_t = s \right] - \mathbb{E}_{\pi}  [G_{t:t+n}^{\pi}|S_t = s]\Bigr\rvert$$

which is further written in form of trajectory probabilities (for easier comprehension):

$$\max_s \Bigl\lvert \sum_j p_j^s(R_{t:t+n}^j+\gamma^n V_{t+n-1}^j(S_{t + n})) - \sum_j p_j^s(R_{t:t+n}^j+\gamma^n V_{\pi}^j(S_{t + n})) \Bigr\rvert$$

Now the equation can be simplified by cancelling the reward terms ($R_{t:t+n}^j$) as they are the same for a trajectory, and thus is common to both the terms  we get:
$$\max_s \Bigl\lvert \gamma^n\sum_j p_j^s( V_{t+n-1}^j(S_{t + n})-V_{\pi}^j(S_{t + n}))\Bigr\rvert$$

This is basically the expectation of the deviation of each and every state at the $n$ th step (from its actual value $V_{\pi}$,), starting from $S_t = s$ and multiplied by a discount factor.

Now using the identity $E[X] \leq \max X$ we get:

$$\max_s \Bigl\lvert \gamma^n\sum_j p_j^s( V_{t+n-1}^j(S_{t + n})-V_{\pi}^j(S_{t + n}))\Bigr\rvert \leq \max \Bigl\lvert \gamma^n( V_{t+n-1}^j(S_{t + n})-V_{\pi}^j(S_{t + n}))\Bigr\rvert$$

Which can finally be written as:
$$\max_s \Bigl\lvert \mathbb{E}_{\pi} \left[ G_{t:t+n} \mid S_t = s \right] - v_{\pi}(s) \Bigr\rvert \leq \max \Bigl\lvert \gamma^n( V_{t+n-1}^j(S_{t + n})-V_{\pi}^j(S_{t + n}))\Bigr\rvert$$

Now the RHS is true for only those states reachable from $S_t = s$ via a trajectory, but since it has a maximizing operation we can include the whole state space in the $\max$ operation without any problem to finally write:

$$\max_s \Bigl\lvert \mathbb{E}_{\pi} \left[ G_{t:t+n} \mid S_t = s \right] - v_{\pi}(s) \Bigr\rvert \leq \max_s \Bigl\lvert \gamma^n( V_{t+n-1}(s)-V_{\pi}(s))\Bigr\rvert$$

which concludes the proof.